# Ghost with multiple subdirectories

Tags: node.js, ghost-blog

I am using [Ghost](https://ghost.org/) for a website I am making. I want to have a homepage, a project page and a blog page. The project and the blog page should be editable using Ghost. This would be my site structure if possible:

```
www
|---index.html
|
|---/projects
|   |
|   |---project*.html
|
|---/blog
|   |
|   |---blogpost*.html
```

So how would I go about doing this. Should I run 2 Ghost instances? (I hope this is not needed.) Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this using a single instance of Ghost, but you would need to add appropriate logic for loading your pages and possibly blog content using Ajax requests. It could get a bit tricky, but it seems that your structure is not that complex to be able to do what you want. However, your static pages would be just blog entries marked as "static" rather than physical files as you described.

You may take a look at our theme which does exactly what you describing, by separating the portfolio page (which are static pages) from the blog entries. The theme itself might not work for you, but you can investigate the javascript code and make modifications to your theme to follow similar structure.

[Here is the demo](http://creator-demo.phantomus.com). You can download it from About page within the theme itself and read the way its configured.

Cheers,